# Integer.Parse(String) throws exception

Tags: java, exception, integer

I'm new at android developement, new to Java too. Originally, I'm a C# and C++ programmer, so this is kind of suspect to me. I wrote this code

```
String[] teile = temp.split(" ");

int[] teileInt = new int[] 
{
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50
} ;

for (int i = 0; i < teile.length; ++i) {
    try {
        Integer integer = new Integer(teile[i]);
        //int d = Integer.parseInt(teile[i]);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, teile[i] + getMessagesFromException(ex), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //

}
```

Both expressions turn into the same Exception!

(Cant post an image)

The Toast says:

```
40null Invalid int: "40"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid
int: "40"
```

Im sorry, but I can' t figure out whats wrong... Is 40 not an Integer?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Your code does not show what the content of temp is, which constructs teile.

Comment: Post the relevant code where the exception arises. Also, post the content of `temp` String variable.

Comment: teileInt is never used. could you share temp's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. `Integer integer = new Integer(teile[i].trim());`
I assume you have a leading or a trailing space in `teile[i]`.

Comment: or better split by `"\\s+"`

Comment: @AndreiNicusan Yes, that could help too. Agreed.

Comment: youre answer was really helpfull! didnt expect it would be neceressary to trim() those!!